# Too few arguments to function 'fgets'?

Tags: c

Literally have only been learning to program for two hours now. I am using Sams Teach Yourself C in one hour a day and I am stuck on just a seemingly simply exercise on lesson 2.

> 5. What does the following program do? (Enter, compile, and run it.)
>
> ```
> /* ex02-05.c */
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <string.h>
> int main(void)
> {
>     char buffer[256];
>
>     printf( "Enter your name and press <Enter>:\n");
>     fgets( buffer );
>
>     printf( "\nYour name has %d characters and spaces!",
>                      strlen( buffer ));
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

So the back of the book says that the end result should allow me to enter and name and have it tell me the amount of spaces and characters. However, I am getting an error that states that there are "too few arguments to function fgets on line 9"?

Comment: `fgets()` takes three arguments.Period. BTW: first lookup the *types* of the argumentst that it expects.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets

Comment: [`fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) takes 3 arguments. The first is the character buffer where the retrieved info should be stored, the second is the number of characters to read, the 3rd is the stream to read them from.

Comment: My theory is that the original code probably used `gets`, and was later changed to use `fgets` - but arguments weren't fixed.

Comment: @MatteoItalia My thoughts as well. Which doesn't speak well for the quality of the book. (OP: What edition of this book are you using?)

Comment: Here's what seems to be the errata for that book. It does mention this issue: http://onjofilms.blogspot.com/2014/09/errata-for-sams-teach-yourself-c.html

Comment: I've replaced the "fgets" with "gets" and indeed it worked! I appreciate those who were explaining fgets to me but this chapter is literally about what statements and comments are. This exercise i'm sure was suppose to be a fun "look you can program too!" type of deal. this is the **seventh** edition of the book.I see I was downvoted, If I find more problems such as this should I avoid taking them to this forum?

Comment: `gets` isn't even in the standard anymore. You're lucky it compiled.

Comment: @NoobNoob use Google first; if you cannot find the solution or that problem being asked then do ask. If the code is from a book, then make it clear that it is from the book, and which book and which edition. And remember to format the post right.

Comment: Thumb rule: When in doubt check `man`. When seriously paranoid, check the source code. Works best. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an error in the book. Like the compiler said, `fgets()` requires three arguments.

This was probably the result of an overeager search-and-replace to substitute `fgets()` for the deprecated `gets()`. What was intended here was probably either:

```
gets(buffer);
```

which will produce a warning on most modern compilers, or

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
```

to pass the correct arguments to `fgets()`.

This error is troubling, as it suggests that other parts of the book may have been written or updated carelessly. Tread carefully.